Form Control valueChanges observable in NgOnInit cannot be subscribed after navigating to same page
I have a page that navigates to itself with different parameter. This makes the NgOnInit don't be executed again. Sadly, in the NgOnInit I have an observable subscribed to deal with value changes in a particular form control. This works fine as long as the page doesn't navigate to same page. Example:


ngOnInit() {
    ...
    this.myForm.control['stateId'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), pairwise()).subscribe(
      ([old, new]) = {
        //do something with old and new values
      }
    );
    ...
}



Before, I had a similar issue dealing with the new parameter after navigating to same page, and I solved it by doing this:


ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
    (param) => {
      //do something with param
    }
  );
  ...
}



How I can subscribe the valueChanges observable for a similar scenario?

How do you navigate to the same page with different parameter? I'd be easier if you showed the navigation code.

I don't think that makes the difference. I am doing it like..
this.router.navigate( [ "../user/" + userId ], { relativeTo: this.activateRoute} );
And of course, in the router I have the path like "user/:id" . By the way, I don't want to destroy the navigation system.

We can use a switchMap to switch to the new valueChanges listener when the route params changes this will solve the issue!
private subscription!: Subscription;
private sub!: Subscription = new Subscription();

ngOnInit() {
  ...
  this.sub.add(
  this.activatedRoute.params.pipe(
    switchMap((param) => {
        return this.myForm.control['stateId'].valueChanges.pipe(startWith(''), pairwise()).pipe(
          tap(([old, new]) = {
            //do something with old and new values
        }));
    })
  ));
  ...
}


Isn't an anti-pattern having a subscribe inside another subscribe? Thanks for your help.

@Mikaelangel Actually you're right, updated my answer using switchMap!
